# How to avoid update when form entries are not changed

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Presently In my application , on click of grid row , i fill the control of the page with the grid row entries. I have a UPDATE button to save the changes . But even if the don't modify any control values and click on Update button , updation will be done with same  values. that triggers a entry to log table .

How can I make the form to call the update only when the values of the controls are different than what is being loaded to them when i click grid.

**UPDATE :**
Application is not using any pattern like MVVM . the structure what is being followed is very slimier to win forms except the UI . For db interaction ADO.net . It was built already when i joined to this project &  even I am new to wpf.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Are you using a pattern such as MVVM? Please explain the design of your application.

Comment: Do you have the ItemsSource of the GridView binded?

Comment: i have the item source of data grid . but i am not updating the entries in grid itself . i load dem to separate controls like text box , combo box etc

Answer (score 2):

I think that you need to do some change tracking on the Entities displayed in the grid. Whenever an Update is executed you check the state of the entities and only update those entities where it's needed. Basically you need to intercept at the level of Property Setters to keep track of changes in the entity. think about:

1. Using a base class that has some functionality for keeping track of the state of an entity. Very simple: a Boolean hasChanged or more "complex" an Enum with Added, Modified and Deleted or something.
2. Derive other entities from this base class
3. Work with public properties and private backing fields to intercept property modifications
4. When property modifications are executed store the information in a Boolean or Enum in the base class
5. When the update is initiated by the user loop through the entities presented in the Grid and pick those that have changes and send them to the database.

Some helpfull theory about this might be:

[Change tracking on businees objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80182/how-to-track-changes-to-business-objects)

[Using Properties C# programming guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

[ADO.NET Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407090.aspx)

I don't know from your question how tightly the coupling is between the user interface and the database (ADO.NET DataTables or so...). The idea presented above requires some "decoupling" of things. But, is a good basis for further functionalities in your application and can give you some ease of work, clear framework, improved maintenance and might increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way to do this is to add a handler to controls, that are used to get user input, that will set some boolean property, e.d. RowWasEdited, to true. Then check this property on UPDATE button click event, do neccessary actions, and set it to false.

But I'm sure that there is something more elegant than this.

Comment: Your solution will work but still "smells" a bit. I think it's better to keep track of changes on the business entities itself instead of keeping a private Boolean on a form to check for updates.